# Correct drift from IMU with magnetic sensor

Tags: sensor, magnetics, accelerometer, imu, drift

Is it possible to correct the drift from the IMU by setting an external magnetic sensor as the reference point (zero) of the magnetometer in the IMU. For example, tracking the position of the wrist, by having the magnetic field next to the magnetometer of the IMU, the zero or reference point will always stay at the position of the wrist.

Comment: Don't know if this can help you ... it is a bit "complicated : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6471153/

Comment: @Antonio51 Yes I saw that article indeed. As you said a bit complicated, couldn't fully understand if it was talking about the use case of an external magnetic sensor to compensate the the gyro drift with the magnetometer.

Comment: To be "simple", the problem with IMUs is the same as with "integrators" used in electronics with op-amps. These are subject to a drift resulting from the integration of an offset voltage, for example. IMUs are subject to the same problems, since the sensors provide, for example for accelerometers, a quantity which must be "integrated" twice to obtain first a speed, then a distance. Each time, a constant is also added.

Comment: IMUs also provide the "same" information as accelerometers, but for "rotations" (angular rotation speed). Also to be integrated ... to provide rotation angles this time. And that, in the 3 axes... Same problems as the inertial units of the planes which had to be regularly recalibrated on the ground... Hence the need to "recalibrate" in one point and one direction.

Comment: Very interesting "paper", http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1366127/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks! that's giving me some great inside. It says that hard iron distortions, like a permanent magnet, will cause a permanent bias to be present in the magnetic measurements, which leads to a shift in the center of the circle. I'm wondering if this can be used in a positive way for locking the center of the circle from the magnetometer to a permanent magnet, and doing so keep this as a reference point for the gyroscope to keep it from drifting.. if this makes sense.